# Is File.ReadLines buffering read lines?

Tags: c#

I have a very long text file (about 600MB of text) which I want to parse line by line. I can simply use `StreamReader.ReadLine()` method, but I'd like to know if using LINQ with `File.ReadLines(filepath)` will eat a lot of memory or maybe after line is "read" into separate string variable it is removed from memory.

In other words, `File.ReadLines()` will build whole array of string in memory as I will go through the file or will it work similarly to `StreamReader.ReadLine()` using the same amount of memory (i.e. single line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.ReadLines` is literally a wrapper around `StreamReader.ReadLine()`, which will be called once per iteration. It does not do any of its own buffering, but `StreamReader` will buffer a small amount to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use
>   ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before
>   the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must
>   wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access
>   the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files,
>   ReadLines can be more efficient.

So it looks like `ReadLines` reads one line at a time.