# How do I load just one non-header record, using SSIS, to a table?

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file with several hundred thousand rows. This file has no header rows. I need to load just the first row into a hold table and then read the last field into a variable. This hold table has just two columns, first one for most of the row, second for the field I need to move into the variable. Optionally, how can I read this one field, from the flat file, into a variable?

I should note that I am currently loading the entire file, then reading just the first row to get the FILE_NBR into a variable. I would like to speed it up a bit by only loading that first row, instead of the entire file.

My source is a fixed position file, so I am putting all fields except for the last 6 bytes into one field and then the last 6 bytes into the FILE_NBR field.

I am looking to only load one record, instead of the entire file, as I only need that field from one record (the number is the same on every record in the file), for comparison to another table.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: How do you know what the last field is of the first line?

Comment: It is a fixed position file, so I am putting all fields except for the last 6 bytes into one field and then the last 6 bytes into the FILE_NBR field. I am looking to only load one record, instead of the entire file, as I only need that field from one record (the number is the same on every record in the file), for comparison to another table.

Answer (score 2):

For the use case you're describing, I would likely use a Data Flow Task that is a Script Component (acting as source) to an OLE/ADO Destination.

### Assumptions

A variable named `@[User::CurrentFileName]` exists, is of type String and is populated with a fully qualified path to the source file.

The Script Component, acting as Source, will have two columns (ROR, FILENBR) defined of the appropriate length (not to exceed 4000 characters) and 6 and the output buffer is left as the default of Output0

Approximate source component code (ensure you set CurrentFileName as a ReadOnly variable in the component)

```
// A variable for holding our data
string inputRow = "";

// Convert the SSIS space variable into a C# space variable
string sourceFile = Dts.Variables["CurrentFileName"].Value.ToString();

// Read from the source file 
// (I was lazy, feel free to improve this)
foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(sourceFile))
{  
    inputRow = line;
    // We have the one row we want, let's blow this popsicle stand
    break;
}  

// TODO split line into RestOfRow and FileNumber
// Guessing here, likely have the logic wrong 
// and am off by one is all but guaranteed
int lineLen = line.Length;

// Slice out to the final 6 characters
string ror = line.Substring(0,lineLen-6);
// Python would much more elegant
string fileNumber = line.Substring(lineLen);

// Now that we have the two pieces we need, let's do the SSIS specific thing
// Create a row in our output buffer and assign values
Output0Buffer.AddRow();
Output0Buffer.ROR = ror;
Output0Buffer.FILENBR = fileNumber;
```

### Ref

- [Is File.ReadLines buffering read lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258187/is-file-readlines-buffering-read-lines)